# Installing ipython with python 2.7

Tags: python, centos, ipython

Trying to install ipython on Centos 6.8. It originally had Python 2.6 and I got Python 2.7 installed.

Which python returns /usr/bin/python and python2.7 gets me the 2.7 version.

How do I install ipython using pip and associate it to 2.7 instead of the default 2.6?

Comment: install pip for python2.7, then do `python -m pip install ipython`

Comment: pip is already included in 2.7.12 right? python -m pip install ipython returns  no module named pip

Comment: Usually it is, but from experience that depends how you installed it. You can try `python -m ensurepip` or downloading and executing the get-pip script. If you installed with a package manager, you may want to check first if it also packages pip.

Comment: thanks! was able to successfully install  (at least no errors). However starting ipython gives the following errors: File "./ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
ImportError: No module named traitlets.config.application

Comment: is `traitlets` at the latest version? If not try upgrading it.

Comment: Asked for few more modules and went ahead and installed one by one. I am all done now. Many thanks for your help.